# Multidimensional array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, numerical-methods

I'm trying to create a numerical model.

The problem I'm facing is quite confusing for me, for the velocity governed by this equation:

```
    u(xi)= ∑j=1N Mij(x1,....,xN)fj
```

I have this matrix equation **U=MF** where U and F are 2N by 1 vectors and M is a 2N by 2N matrix in two dimensions.

The code I have for them in two dimensions is:

```
N=length(xN);
u(1:N)=ux; 
u(N+1:2*N)=uy; 
M(1:2*N,1:2*N)=0;
```

I've tried to do the same in three dimensions and got the following:

```
N=length(xN);
ux=u(1:N); 
uy=u(N+1:2N); 
uz=u(N+2:3*N); 
M(1:3*N,1:3*N)=0;
```

I am pretty sure I'm wrong somewhere, can anyone please enlighten me?

Comment: Other than `uz=u(2*N+1:3*N)` (typo?) I don’t see any issues. Why do you think you’re wrong?

Comment: It's not a typo, unfortunately. Can you please explain how did you come to such a result for uz?

Comment: Well, I presume that `uy` and `uz` contain different data, that `u` is formed by concatenating the vectors `ux`, `uy` and `uz`. If so, the first one has indices `1:N`, the next one has indices `N+1:2*N`, and the third one has indicates `2*N+1:3*N`. Each one starts at the element right after the last element of the previous one. You have `N+2:3*N`, which is longer than `N` and overlaps the `N+1:2*N` range of `uy`.